# Non-linear Least Squares fit does not minimize

Tags: python, least-squares, scipy-optimize

I am trying to fit a decay with a sum of three exponentials and am using the code below. All looks fine superficially, but the optimization does not converge (or do anything for that matter). When I call lsq_res.x, I can see that the parameters are the same as the initial guess. I suspect the problem in the minimization function itself (def fun(x, t, y):...) and am not sure whether I am passing the variables correctly. Help with this is greatly appreciated as this would also allow me to apply this to other models!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from scipy.optimize import least_squares

def Intensity(x_data, A21, T21, A22, T22, A23, T23, y0):
    I_model=A21*np.exp(-x_data/T21)+A22*np.exp(-x_data/T22)+A23*np.exp(-x_data/T23)+y0
    return I_model


#generate example data set (should be replaced by load of csv data file)
def gen_data(t, b1, c1, b2, c2, b3, c3, y0, noise=0, n_outliers=0, random_state=0):
    y = b1 * np.exp(-t / c1) + b2 * np.exp(-t / c2) + b3 * np.exp(-t / c3)+y0

    rnd = np.random.RandomState(random_state)
    error = noise * rnd.randn(t.size)
    outliers = rnd.randint(0, t.size, n_outliers)
    error[outliers] *= 10

    return y + error
# these are the parameters used to calculate the function, correspond to my first guess
y0 = 0.5
b1 = 0.25
c1 = .01
b2 = 0.4
c2 = .3
b3 = 0.35
c3 = 10

t_min = -3
t_max = 2
n_points = 1000

x_data = np.logspace(t_min, t_max, n_points)
y_data = gen_data(x_data, b1, c1, b2, c2, b3, c3, y0, noise=0.1, n_outliers=3) 

# the following is the minimization function where the appropriate model needs to be entered in the return line. 

def fun(x, t, y):
    return Intensity(x_data, A21, T21, A22, T22, A23, T23, y0) - y_data 
x0 = np.array([A21, T21, A22, T22, A23, T23, y0]) # give starting values for the fit parameters in the model


res_lsq = least_squares(fun, x0, args=(x_data, y_data)) #this performs the actual minimization of

y_lsq = gen_data(x_data, *res_lsq.x)
```

Answer (score 1):

As I see the problem, you try to find the best parameters for the Intensity function.

I suggest you use the **curve_fit** function of scipy.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def Intensity(x_data, A21, T21, A22, T22, A23, T23, y0 ):
    I_model=A21*np.exp(-x_data/T21)+A22*np.exp(-x_data/T22)+A23*np.exp(-x_data/T23)+y0
    return I_model


#generate example data set (should be replaced by load of csv data file)
def gen_data(t, b1, c1, b2, c2, b3, c3, y0, noise=0, n_outliers=0, random_state=0):
    y = b1 * np.exp(-t / c1) + b2 * np.exp(-t / c2) + b3 * np.exp(-t / c3)+y0

    rnd = np.random.RandomState(random_state)
    error = noise * rnd.randn(t.size)
    outliers = rnd.randint(0, t.size, n_outliers)
    error[outliers] *= 10

    return y + error

#%%
# these are the parameters used to calculate the function, correspond to my first guess
y0 = 0.5
b1 = 0.25
c1 = .01
b2 = 0.4
c2 = .3
b3 = 0.35
c3 = 10

t_min = -3
t_max = 2
n_points = 1000

x_data = np.logspace(t_min, t_max, n_points)
y_data = gen_data(x_data, b1, c1, b2, c2, b3, c3, y0, noise=0.1, n_outliers=3)

res = curve_fit(Intensity, x_data, y_data)
```

the docs can be found [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html). I hope I did not misunderstand your question.

If you want to minimize the function, you should provide static parameter values and an initial guess for the variables.
In your question, the parameter values are not given.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to curve_fit! This is helped solve my issue and I am now able to perform a non-linear least squares fit.

Comment: No worries, can you mark the question as answered and upvote?